# Usage of neither alone at the end of sentence

Tags: neither-nor

Good afternoon everyone,
I have a grammar dilemma regarding the usage of "neither" at the end of my sentence:

> Those, who did not know God here and now and who did not serve Him
> through service to their neighbours here and now, neither will see Him
> in eternity.

Is it correct or should change the end of it? An option comes to my mind but I am afraid it does not catch the idea:

> ...will not see him even/also in eternity.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: _Neither_ implies a _nor_ (a second negative). Better to say _will not see Him in eternity either_.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting. While "neither" doesn't *always* imply a "nor," she's right that in this case, it does. It even more than does. For "neither" to work there, you'd need to change the conjunction "and" to "nor," but that'd require reworking the sentence, and once we start doing that, we then have to start addressing several other problems it has, like the extraneous comma, how using the past tense is inconsistent with your usage of "now," and possibly considering adding "in the" before "here and now," which is editing and would exceed the purview of the question as per this site.

Comment: The cited text could be considered syntactically valid with a bit of creative parsing and a contrived context. *[As for] **Those** [two people] [, who didn't go to church,] - **neither** [of them] will go to heaven.*

Comment: Side note: "did not ... here and now" should likely be "do not ... here and now". The phrase "here and now" emphasizes the present, and "did" is past tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Those, who did not know God here and now and who did not serve Him through service to their neighbours here and now, neither will see Him in eternity.

1. Expunge the comma after "those."
2. Insert a comma after "here and now."

3."Neither" is a conjunction that usually pairs with "nor." They are members of a class called "corresponsive conjunctions"; e.g., "both-and," "as-as," "as-so," "if-then," "such-as," "such-that," "either-or," "neither-nor," "whether-or," "(al)though-yet."

I'm trying to read the problem sentence more closely as to its sense. Is it referring to two groups of people, each group with one sin? For example, (1) Those, who knew not God here and now, and (2) [those] who served Him not through service to their neighbours here and now. Not sure if this is what was meant, but the sentence certainly can be understood that way. If so, then the introductory "nor" (as part of the corresponsive conjunction "neither-nor") would fit; as in,

"Those who did not know God here and now, nor those who did not serve Him through service to their neighbours here and now, neither will [they] see Him in eternity."

If it's one group of people with two sins, then perhaps the following revised construction:

"Those will not see God in eternity who neither knew him here and now, nor served Him through service to their neighbors."

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your precise answer and effort to explore the meaning of the sentence to its roots.
Regarding your question, the second case described by you is the one I am trying to express in the sentence. (One group, two sins)
Your answer is very useful to me because I am still finding the way to express myself, especially in terms of syntactic order of words in a sentence.
Wish you all the best! :)

Comment: You're very welcome!